# accessing external hdd from application

Tags: hard-drive

I'm new to ubuntu.
I have been given a pc that runs ubuntu 20.04. with this pc I need to work on files stored on an external hdd.
I can see the hdd and access the files from the "file explorer" (using the windows terminology).
however when I need to navigate to the hdd from inside an app that I need to work with, I cannot see the hdd in the list of folders that I can import the files from. Nor I find a way to navigate outside those folders.

what is going on?

Comment: Most likely the app is a snap app.  Should give name of app in your question.  Go to software store, find app, and check for permissions.  Give app permissions.  Can also see if app has a deb version and use that one.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably the root cause. Each Snap apps has its own set of permissions (what it is allowed to do and what not). Accessing external devices are not enabled by default.